# backup without overwriting old backups

Tags: backup, cron

I'm using Ubuntu server 14.04 to backup all data from '/mnt/test/ folder' to '/home/john/' with TAR and archive to stuff.tar.gz and to make it to backup automatical.

I use cron to backup it every week so what if i want to use cron to create an additional backup file instead of overwriting the existing one? So, after month I'd have 4 backups, each with a unique name. Is there a way? Script ar other backup tool what would do that?

Comment: Just add a time (date) stamp to the tar command. backup_`date +%F`.tar.gz

Comment: when i did this (backup_`date +%F`.tar.gz) i get backup_date+%F.tar.gz and no data.i'm new at linux so i think i did some error

Comment: Those are back ticks ` and not singel quotes '. you substitute that "backup_`date +%F`.tar.gz" in your tar command, where you are using "stuff.tar.gz" If you need help, post the command you actually run + any actual error message.

Comment: sorry for stupid question, how to type back tick?

Comment: On my keyboard it is on the ~ key on the upper left next to the number one.

Comment: now i get stuff_.tar.gz and i use same tar command I thought it would be two backups with names like stuff00:02.tar.gz and second stuff00:04.tar.gz or something like that

Comment: hard to help you when you do not post your command.

Comment: sorry tar -cpzf /home/john/stuff_`date+%F`.tar.gz /mnt/test

Comment: You need a space in "date+%F" like this " tar -cpzf /home/john/stuff_`date +%F`.tar.gz /mnt/test " if dtat is alised, use the full path " tar -cpzf /home/john/stuff_`/bin/date +%F`.tar.gz /mnt/test "

Comment: Then I make changes in /mnt/tests folder like put new files in it, it still overwrites ant theres is one backup stuff_2014-05-29

Comment: This is because the "date" has not changed. You can add hours/minutes to the date command, see man date. It will work if you only run your backup daily. If you want an alternate tool, I highly suggest rsync .

Comment: i started with but rsync doesn't compress it just moves files

Comment: yes, but you can use rsync over a network and you essentially have a mirror. rsync to a directory tar the directory daily. you will have to find a strategy that works for you.

Comment: i'm mounted shared flder in windows 7 _mount -t cifs //10.0.0.1/sesktop -o username=john /mnt/test_ and than with cron to /home/john and keep all backups there, if i would like to do this i must install cygwin i think it's called

Comment: I do not think you need cygwin as you are running chron and tar on Ubuntu.

Comment: no no if i would like to it with rsync than i think i would need cygwin

Comment: Yes, but there would be no benefit to using `rsync` since you will just be copying a new file, not updating a slightly modified one that is already there.  FYI, you can use `smbclient` in the script to copy to the windows share rather than keeping it mounted.

Comment: i don't know how to script, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a date in the name of your archive

```
tar -cpzf /home/john/stuff_`/bin/date +%F`.tar.gz /mnt/test
```

Comment: Add hour / minute ;) "date +%F %l:%M"